# How to delete Bullets from an Unordered List using CSS?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, master-pages

I have this in my CSS:

```
.MainMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top:105px;
    left:15px;    
    background-color: #67E300;  
    color:White;
    border-style:double;
    border-color:White;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

And this inside of the MasterPage:

```
<div class="MainMenu">
        <uc2:MainMenu ID="MainMenu1" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

And finally this code inside of the UserControl MainMenu:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainMenu.ascx.cs" Inherits="LoCompro.UserControls.MainMenu" %>
<ul>
    <li>Inico</li>
    <li>Navegar Por Categoria</li>
    <li>Navegar Por Marca</li>
    <li>Buscar</li>
</ul>
```

Edit (forgot to ask the question, lol):

Using that code doesn't delete the bullet list. I don't want any bullets because I want to simulate a menu.

Thanks guys. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing the `list-style-type` on the `UL`, not on the `DIV` containing the UL.

```
.MainMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top:105px;
    left:15px;    
    background-color: #67E300;  
    color:White;
    border-style:double;
    border-color:White;
}


.MainMenu ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it just

```
list-style:none;
```

rather than

```
list-style-type:none;
```

In your li/ol/ul section

For example

```
ol.foo>li {
    list-style:none;
}
```

or

```
.classThatTheListElementIsAMemberOf {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: or `list-style-type`, I believe they're synonyms/aliases, but yes. Up-voted.

Comment: So you're saying use that style property inside of the UserControl where I actually declare the unorderedlist, etc.

Is there a way for me to use my CSS instead. I'm not comfortable mixing styling and content. Thank you! :·)

Comment: They're not quite aliases. list-style lets you set all the list style rules in one rule (think font vs. font-family).

Comment: @Joe, upvoted for the clarification. Live and learn, thanks =)

Comment: @Papuccino, but the `list-style:none` in the CSS file for the `ul`, example: `ul {list-style: none; }`

Comment: Specifically, the other *list-style* properties are *position* and *image*.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the `list-style-type` to the `div`, not to the `ul` inside the `div`. Try this instead:

```
.MainMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top:105px;
    left:15px;    
    background-color: #67E300;  
    color:White;
    border-style:double;
    border-color:White;
}

.MainMenu ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

This will apply the `list-style-type` to any `ul` inside an item with the css class `MainMenu` defined on it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this in your CSS:

```
.MainMenu ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

It will match the ul within the .MainMenu div, which is the final result of your above-posted code.